# Probability - Change of variables problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider the continuous random numbers $x$ and $y$. Their joint probability density is given by $P(x,y) = Acos(x+y)$ for $x \geq 0, y\geq 0$, and $x+y \leq B$, where $B\geq0$ is another constant.
(a) What's the largest value of B for which this is a valid probability density?
(b)If we define a third random number by the equation $z=x+y$, what is the probability density for z?(you don't have to evaluate the normalization constant)

My attempt:
(a) For $P(x,y)$ to be a valid p.d.f, $Acos(x+y)$must always $\geq 0$. So $x+y\leq B\leq \pi/2$
(b)$P(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{z-x}Acos(x+y)dydx$ and evaluate this?

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) looks OK to me. But for part (b), it seems like you're thinking of the CDF. You should have
$$
F_{Z}(z) =P(X+Y \le z) =  \int_0^z \int_0^{z-x} A \cos(x+y) \; dy \, dx
= \cdots =  A (z \sin(z)+\cos(z)-1)
$$
and then we see 
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \left[ A (z \sin(z)+\cos(z)-1)\right] = Az \cos z.
$$